# Displaying a plot correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to know if it is possible to save my plot correctly without having the legend onto the plots

Basically, my program uses other functions to solve differential equations about the evolution of rabbits and foxes to plot different evolutions depending on the initial values of their population.
The problem is that, as you can see, the legend on the right hand side spills over the plot

Here is my code :
'''

```
CI=np.array([100,50])
t,y=resolution(CI)
L1=[y[k][0] for k in range(len(y))]
R1=[y[k][1] for k in range(len(y))]

CI=np.array([100,130])
t,y=resolution(CI)
L2=[y[k][0] for k in range(len(y))]
R2=[y[k][1] for k in range(len(y))]

CI=np.array([200,100])
t,y=resolution(CI)
L3=[y[k][0] for k in range(len(y))]
R3=[y[k][1] for k in range(len(y))]

CI=np.array([50,50])
t,y=resolution(CI)
L4=[y[k][0] for k in range(len(y))]
R4=[y[k][1] for k in range(len(y))]


fig,axs=plt.subplots(2,2, sharey=True)

axs[0,0].plot(t,L1,'b')
axs[0,0].plot(t,R1,'r')
axs[0,0].set_title('R0=100 et F0=50')

axs[0,1].plot(t,L2,'b')
axs[0,1].plot(t,R2,'r')
axs[0,1].set_title('R0=100 et F0=130')

axs[1,0].plot(t,L3,'b')
axs[1,0].plot(t,R3,'r')
axs[1,0].set_title('R0=200 et F0=100')

axs[1,1].plot(t,L4,'b', label='Rabbits')
axs[1,1].plot(t,R4,'r', label='Fox')
axs[1,1].set_title('R0=100 et F0=100')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Individuals number')
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.label_outer()

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 1.2))
plt.suptitle('Population evolution')
plt.savefig('Fin',dpi=1200)
```

'''

And this is what the figure looks like :
[image: The plot I have]

Comment: Where do you want the legend to be instead relative to the other subplots?

Comment: If possible, on the right, next to the plots but without having it spilling over them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push the legend around you can use `bbox_to_anchor` as you likely tried.  In order to save the figure without the edge legend cut off of the image, you can use the `bbox_inches='tight'` argument in `plt.savefig()`.

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.6, 1.3)) # changed position
plt.suptitle('Population evolution')
plt.savefig('Fin', dpi=1200, bbox_inches='tight') # added bbox_inches argument
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you replace the last three lines of code in your question with the three lines of code in my answer? This worked fine for me.

Comment: I ask because it worked on my machine like this, albeit with synthetic data.  Shouldn't affect the effectiveness of the code though.  Did you close any programs accessing the image?  If you replace the `plt.savefig...` line with `plt.show()` you can display the plot without saving.  This makes it easier to make small adjustments.

Comment: Oh yeah, it works when I'm also changing the line `plt.legend` 
When I'm plotting with `plt.show()', I can't see the entire legend but no worries for that, all I wanted was to have my figure saved correctly, and it is the case.